# SQL: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Tags: sql, group-by

Code is not executing, syntax is completely correct. I don't understand

```
SELECT DWCUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, DWPRODUCT.P_CODE, SUM(DWDAYSALESFACT.SALE_UNITS*DWDAYSALESFACT.SALE_PRICE) AS TOTSALES 
FROM DWDAYSALESFACT NATURAL JOIN DWCUSTOMER   
GROUP BY ROLLUP (DWCUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, DWPRODUCT.P_CODE)  
ORDER BY DWCUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, DWPRODUCT.P_CODE;
```

After execution: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: "syntax is completely correct" yet you get a syntax error... how can you be absolutely sure? Use backticks.

Comment: What database are you using? What do you expect grouping on `rollup()` to do?

Comment: I'm trying to list the total sales by customer and by product, with subtotals by customer and a grand total for product sales

Comment: So what is your question? Are you expecting somebody to debug this for you? If so you should provide some sample data, describe what you want to achieve (input, expected output), and optimally pass on a `sqlfiddle`. Then I also encourage you to include your database (postgres etc...) as a tag to attract the attention of the specialists of that particular database technology. The more effort you put into your question, the likeliest you are to find some valuable answers.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I'm obviously new to this language and I wrongly assumed this would be a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't join the DWProduct table but you selected from it in the first line. Add another join and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
GROUP BY DWCUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, DWPRODUCT.P_CODE WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Result: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon." Also still have the 'GROUP' error